# Create a specially formatted LIB file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-libraries

Is it possible to create a LIB file which doesn't expose some of its functions to the public?

I mean, I can open any lib file and see every single function of it, not just the "public APIs". Also if I quickly make a prototype for it manually, then I can even call it.

I've got no special intentions with it, I'm just interested if it's possible.

Comment: Declare functions `static` and they can't be accessed from another file.

Comment: you can use an Anonymous Namespace.
see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions) for more details.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560892/symbol-visibility-and-namespace