# How to use the __attribute__((visibility("default")))?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile

Reading [Visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) in the GNU wiki, it is clear.

Taking [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) example from C++ Tutorials

```
// classes example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area() {return width*height;}
};

void Rectangle::set_values (int x, int y) {
  width = x;
  height = y;
}
```

Is it possible to make `area()` public and `set_values(int,int)` local as shown in the first link without altering the code?

I wrote my makefile to get the `.so`

```
someproj.so : someproj.cpp
    g++ --std=c++11 -O3 -fPIC -shared someproj.cpp -o someproj.so
```

Modified to make all symbols hidden by adding `-fvisibility=hidden`

```
someproj.so : someproj.cpp
    g++ --std=c++11 -O3 -fvisibility=hidden -fPIC -shared someproj.cpp -o someproj.so
```

Is it possible to customized which functions are exposed by modifying the compilation command above?

Currently using 4.7.2 version of gcc

Comment: Have you also read [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15606403/15416)? That's also written by Niall Douglas, and confirms that you're fighting a data format problem. It's not GCC, it's ELF.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

> Is it possible to customize which functions are exposed by modifying the compilation command above?

No. Compilation option [`-fvisibility=[default|internal|hidden|protected]`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options)
(and note it is *not* a linkage option) makes the compiler attribute the specified dynamic visibility type to *all* global symbols
generated in the compilation unit *except* those that are specifically excluded by having a countervailing `__attribute__((visibility(....)))`
applied *in the source code*. Which makes the answer to your other question:

> Is it possible to make area() public and set_values(int,int) local as shown in the first link without altering the code?

also No.

How *would* you change the source code to make `Rectangle::area()` dynamically
visible while all other global symbols are hidden for dynamic linkage by `-fvisibility=hidden`?
Here is a walk-through:

Let's start with:

**rectangle.cpp (1)**

```
class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area() {return width*height;}

};

void Rectangle::set_values (int x, int y) {
  width = x;
  height = y;
}
```

and simply compile it to a PIC `rectangle.o` so:

```
$ g++ -Wall -c -fPIC rectangle.cpp
```

Then check the global symbol table:

```
$ nm -C rectangle.o
0000000000000000 T Rectangle::set_values(int, int)
```

Note that `Rectangle::area` isn't there. It's not available for
linkage *at all*, so the question of its dynamic visibility just does not arise.

That is because it is defined *inline* in the class definition and never called
in the compilation unit, so gcc need not even compile its definition. It vanishes
from the object file.

`Rectangle::set_values`, on the other hand, is not defined inline, so the compiler
emits a global symbol and definition.

To make `Rectangle::area` eligible for some visibility type, we first need to make
it a global symbol by not defining it inline:

**rectangle.cpp (2)**

```
class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area();

};

int Rectangle::area() {return width*height;}

void Rectangle::set_values (int x, int y) {
  width = x;
  height = y;
}
```

Recompile and again check the global symbol table:

```
$ g++ -Wall -c -fPIC rectangle.cpp
$ nm -C rectangle.o
000000000000001a T Rectangle::set_values(int, int)
0000000000000000 T Rectangle::area()
```

Good. Now a global definition of `Rectangle::area` appears.

Next let's make a shared library `librectangle.so` from `rectangle.o`:

```
$ g++ -o librectangle.so --shared rectangle.o
```

Here are the `Rectangle::*` symbols in its global symbol table:

```
$ nm -C librectangle.so | grep 'Rectangle::'
00000000000005d4 T Rectangle::set_values(int, int)
00000000000005ba T Rectangle::area()
```

And here are the `Rectangle::*` symbols in its *dynamic* symbol table:

```
$ nm -CD librectangle.so | grep 'Rectangle::'
00000000000005d4 T Rectangle::set_values(int, int)
00000000000005ba T Rectangle::area()
```

They're the same.

Now let's hide those symbols for dynamic linkage. We need to *recompile* `rectangle.cpp`
then relink the shared library:

```
$ g++ -Wall -c -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden rectangle.cpp
$ g++ -o librectangle.so --shared rectangle.o
```

Here again are the `Rectangle::*` symbols now in the global symbol table:

```
$ nm -C librectangle.so | grep 'Rectangle::'
0000000000000574 t Rectangle::set_values(int, int)
000000000000055a t Rectangle::area()
```

They're the same as before.

And here are the `Rectangle::*` symbols now in the *dynamic* symbol table:

```
$ nm -CD librectangle.so | grep 'Rectangle::'; echo Done
Done
```

Now there are *none*, thanks to `-fvisibility=hidden`.

Finally, let's make just `Rectangle::area` dynamically visible, keeping all
the other global symbols dynamically hidden. We need to change the source code
again:

**rectangle.cpp (3)**

```
class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    __attribute__((visibility("default"))) int area();

};

int Rectangle::area() {return width*height;}

void Rectangle::set_values (int x, int y) {
  width = x;
  height = y;
}
```

Then recompile and relink:

```
$ g++ -Wall -c -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden rectangle.cpp
$ g++ -o librectangle.so --shared rectangle.o
```

The global symbol table still shows:

```
$ nm -C librectangle.so | grep 'Rectangle::'
00000000000005a4 t Rectangle::set_values(int, int)
000000000000058a T Rectangle::area()
```

And the dynamic symbol table only shows:

```
$ nm -CD librectangle.so | grep 'Rectangle::'
000000000000058a T Rectangle::area()
```

`Rectangle::area` is now the only symbol that the shared library exposes for
dynamic linkage.

**And before you go...**

One thing more about:

> Is it possible to make area() public and set_values(int,int) local as shown in the first link without altering the code?

Making a symbol hidden for dynamic linkage doesn't make it *local*. Dynamic visibility (default|internal|hidden|protected)
is an attribute of *global* symbols only. For linkage purposes, *local* symbols don't exist. The only ways to
make a symbol local that would otherwise be global are:-

- In C or C++ source, qualify its definition with the [`static` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static)
- In C++ source, enclose its definition in an [anonymous namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces)

Then the symbol does not appear in the global, or dynamic, symbol tables.