# Exporting functions from a c++ shared library : ok on Windows, fails on Linux

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, dllexport

(I may have not been optimal for the tags of the question.)

I have a huge C++ library, perfectly tested and working under windows x86 and x64. (On these plateforms visual studio (2019) is used for the compilation.)

I wanted to give a try on linux, with [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-index) that I just installed.

I managed to create *.o files out of the code and to write a little `main.cpp` from which I build an executable as follows :

```
$(CXX) -I$(IDIR) $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp -fpermissive
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS2) -o main main.o $(OBJDIR)*.o -lpthread
```

As expected the executable has a big size, but it does what I expect it to do. Hence I want to stop using *.o files and rather build a shared library that I will link to while compiling my main.

Hence after having built the *.o files, I do a :

```
$(CXX) -shared -o MyLibrary.so $(OBJDIR)/*.o
```

Then I compile my main as follows :

```
$(CXX) -I$(IDIR) $(CXXFLAGS) main_so.cpp -fpermissive
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS2) -o main_so main_so.o -L$(SODIR)MyLibrary.so -lpthread
```

and the second line triggers an "undefined reference" at each call, in the main, of a function from the library. Classic, they mustn't be correctly exported as in am under WSL2. (Yes, I tested, with [How to detect reliably Mac OS X, iOS, Linux, Windows in C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919996/how-to-detect-reliably-mac-os-x-ios-linux-windows-in-c-preprocessor)) The library functions, in the c++, are exported as follows :

```
MYLIB_API void setToto1(/* signature */) ;
// ...
MYLIB_API void setTotoN(/* signature */) ;
```

where MYLIB_API is defined as follows :

```
#ifdef MYLIB_EXPORT
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYLIB_API  __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

and where MYLIB_EXPORT is added to the [preprocessor definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions?view=vs-2019) of the visual studio project of the library. Hence I replaced the previous preprocessor directives with :

```
#ifdef MYLIB_EXPORT
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__)
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#elif __linux__
#define MYLIB_API __attribute__((dllexport))
#else
#error "Unknown compiler"
#endif
#else
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__)
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#elif __linux__
#define MYLIB_API __attribute__((dllimport))
#else
#error "Unknown compiler"
#endif
#endif
```

and added the [preprocessor option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) `-D MYLIB_EXPORT -D __linux__` to the compilation of the *.o files and the assembling of the shared library file.

Nevertheless I keep having (whatever I try to tweak) these warnings at compilation :

```
warning: ‘dllexport’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
```

I didn't have these warnings in the first place before tweaking the preprocessor directive. And if I try to compile my main again (linkind dynamically to the shared library) I got the undefined references again.

I am sure I am missing something, but can't figure out what.

Comment: On Linux there ain't attributes called dllexport, they use something with 'visibility' in the name

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52742992/2466431

Comment: @JVApen So basically you are saying that `MYLIB_API ` definition should (under linux, forget about windows) be modifed with `MYLIB_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))` replacing `#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)` and `#define MYLIB_API` replacing `` and that during for the compilation I have to add the options 1) `-fvisibility=hidden` to hide all MyLib's functions that don't have the MYLIB_API "flag" in the code (see https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) and 2) `-D LIBPRICER_EXPORT` for the "MYLIB_API attribute((visibility("default")))" directive to be activated in the code ?

Comment: If this is what you are saying, I still have the undefined reference error to functions of MyLib wherever I used them in my main.

Comment: Yes, I think so, for both the import and export, I'm not expert on this. I wouldn't know what the issue with main is giving