# Understanding C++ visibility support

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, visibility

-- as described at the [GCC Wiki - Visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility). I have exercised [How to use the **attribute**((visibility("default")))?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52742992/5014688) and [Simple C++ Symbol Visibility Demo](https://github.com/rolsen/demo_symbol_visibility) but still do not understand some parts of the *GCC Wiki - Visibility* article.

At its [Step-by-step_guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility#Step-by-step_guide) you find

> [For every non-templated non-static function definition in your library (both headers and source files), decide if it is publicly used or internally used](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility#line-159)

In the other examples I found that it is sufficient to only decorate the declarations in the header files. Why also decorate the definitions in the source files?

> [If it is publicly used, mark with FOX_API like this: `extern FOX_API PublicFunc()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility#line-160)

I haven't seen this **extern** keyword in the other examples and I have never used it for public functions. Why do I have to use it here?

[The given macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility#line-22-1) starts with

```
#ifdef FOX_DLL // defined if FOX is compiled as a DLL
```

If using **CMake** where or how is `FOX_DLL` defined?

Comment: The question about `FOX_DLL` is Cmake-related, I suggest to move it to dedicated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the other examples I found that it is sufficient to only decorate the declarations in the header files. Why also decorate the definitions in the source files?

If global function is declared in a header and that header is included in source file where function is *defined*, annotation in header will suffice (compiler will indeed pick up the attribute from the header). Otherwise you'll need to annotate it in source code.

> I haven't seen this extern keyword in the other examples and I have never used it for public functions. Why do I have to use it here?

The `extern` keyword is optional in function declarations but it's often used for clarity.

Comment: "*annotation in header will suffice ... Otherwise you'll need to annotate it in source code.*" - How would I call the global function in another source file without header file? For me the note in the [GCC Wiki - Visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) does not make much sense (except by including the source file).

Comment: @Ingo "How would I call the global function in another source file without header file" - by manually declaring `extern void foo()` in source file. Note that header is just that, a bunch of `extern` declarations which are inserted into source file by preprocessor.

Comment: Ah.. yes, of course. Doesn't thought of this.

Answer (score 0):

You might be confused by two opposite approaches to visibility. You name both `GCC` (which comes from the UNIX corner) and `DLL` (which comes from the Windows corner).

UNIX by default has full visibility, Windows by default has no visibility. As a result, to modify these two defaults, you have to move in opposite directions.

C++ (and C prior to it) did not have the notion of shared libraries or visibility, which makes sense: there wasn't much to standardize. You end up with non-portable approaches like this.

Comment: "to modify these two defaults, you have to move in opposite directions" - just wanted to point out that the _recommended_ approach on Linux is to use `-fvisibility=hidden` to hide all symbols by default and then selectively export public ones via `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`. This makes it identical to Windows.