# How can I hide my code perfectly when I build library file in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++, disassembly

I am trying to hide original code from library file which is written in C++. My question is "How can I hide my code securely when I built library file, like .o or .so ?"

### Environment description

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (with WSL2)
- gcc 9.3.0

## Problem description.

### Source code

let's think there is `test.cpp` file

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "This is FOO\n";
}
int bar() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 12;
    std::cout << "This is BAR\n";
    return a + b;
}
char test() {
    std::cout << "This is TEST\n";
    return 'T';
}
```

### How did I build (on terminal)

```
$ g++ -o test.o -c test.cpp -O2
$ g++ -c -fPIC test.cpp -o test.so -O2
```

I built 2 files if there is difference between object file and static object file to solve my problem.

### test.o

You can see like below picture. There is "FOO" "BAR" or something else.

[image: test.o]

and also when I use `nm test.o` it shows function name like `T _Z3barv` `T _Z3foov` etc.

```
$ nm test.o
0000000000000000 r .LC0
000000000000000d r .LC1
000000000000001a r .LC2
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z3foov
0000000000000020 T _Z3barv
0000000000000000 T _Z3foov
0000000000000050 T _Z4testv
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
                 U _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
                 U _ZSt4cout
0000000000000000 b _ZStL8__ioinit
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 U __dso_handle
```

### test.so

This file also shows "FOO" "BAR" things which prints string.

[image: test.so]

like above, when I use `nm test.so`, it shows function name like `T _Z3barv` `T _Z3foov` etc.

```
$ nm test.so
0000000000000000 r .LC0
000000000000000d r .LC1
000000000000001a r .LC2
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 t _GLOBAL__sub_I_test.cpp
0000000000000020 T _Z3barv
0000000000000000 T _Z3foov
0000000000000050 T _Z4testv
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
                 U _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
                 U _ZSt4cout
0000000000000000 b _ZStL8__ioinit
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 U __dso_handle
```

## Question

I want to hide everything securely, so that the malicious cannot disassemble my library easily. Can I hide that **strings** like "FOO" "BAR" "TEST"?

Comment: @luk2302 Oh thank you. Then How can I hide the functions that .cpp used? When I use ```nm test.o``` I can read the function name.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719364/how-to-use-the-attribute-visibilitydefault

Comment: You are probably looking for [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)).

Comment: @S.M. Thank you. I skimmed the link, it looks like what I am looking for.

Comment: @zdf:  Obfuscation is the art of making a source file more difficult to read.

Comment: @zdf Well, I read the wikipedia that you linked, it is not. But I will try to do it to my code :)

Comment: Overall, this is all pointless, hiding stuff in `.o` files. If you are giving your customers `.o` files, then they have full and complete access. Hiding things in it (encryption) will slow things down, which will make customers unhappy. What you do, in real life, is sign an agreement with customers so that they have to pay you _a lot_ when they distribute/leak what you give them (basically NDA), or you just distribute your service as a cloud.

Comment: `Then How can I hide the functions that .cpp used? When I use nm test.o` Please do not ask multiple questions, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions . Which functions do you want to remove from `nm` output? `_Z3barv` or `_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev` or both? Does `objcopy --strip-symbol=_Z3barv` answer your question?

Comment: I always operate under the assumption that a sufficiently motivated party can reverse engineer anything. Additionally I would say obfuscation doesn't so much apply to source code, rather to the output. It is generally achieved with encoders or other tooling.